# How can I change my telegram account name using telethon?

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

I want to change my telegram name using telethon. How can I do this? My main.py file contains following lines of code but it didn't work. can you suggest what wrong I'm doing.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.account import UpdateProfileRequest

client = TelegramClient(<session>, <APICode>, <APIHash>)

with client:
    client(UpdateProfileRequest(first_name=f"Test"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telethon is asynchronous library you need to await in-order to get a result,
further reading over [here](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/quick-start.html)

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.account import UpdateProfileRequest
import asyncio

client = TelegramClient(<session>, <APICode>, <APIHash>)


async def main():
    async with client:
        await client(UpdateProfileRequest(first_name="Test"))

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: thanks @alen for a quick reply. Its working. I think I need to do some hard work asyncio methods :]